# Opening a project in Netbeans but IDE is showing project as a folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I closed my project in Netbeans. However when I try to reopen it, the IDE shows the project as a folder. Package, Classes and everything are all in there. Does anybody know how to open this project?

[image: Open Project Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a new project with existing sources:

File->New Project->Categories:Java->Projects:Java Project with Existing Sources

Not sure how your previous configuration was lost.